# Ошибка "archive/tar: unknown file mode" при сборке проекта на Docker

Tags: python, django, docker, django-channels

Собираю проект Django через `Docker compose up` и возникает ошибка в блоке `Daphne`:

```
[daphne internal] load build context:
failed to solve: archive/tar: unknown file mode ?rwxr-xr-x
```

Вот кусок кода из `docker-compose.yml`:

```
  daphne:
    build: .
    working_dir: /code/src/
    command: ["../wait-for-it.sh", "db:5432", "--",
              "daphne", "-u", "/code/src/daphne.sock",
              "education.asgi:application"]
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    environment:
      - DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=educa.settings.prod
      - POSTGRES_DB=postgres
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    depends_on:
      - db
      - cache
```

код из `asgi.py`:

```
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'education.settings')

django_asgi_app = get_asgi_application()

application = ProtocolTypeRouter({
    'http': django_asgi_app,
    'websocket': AllowedHostsOriginValidator(
        AuthMiddlewareStack(
            URLRouter(chat.routing.websocket_urlpatterns)
        )
    ),
})
```

Код из `config/nginx`:

```
upstream daphne {
    server unix:/code/src/daphne.sock;
}

server {
    #...
    location /ws/ {
        proxy_http_version  1.1;
        proxy_set_header    Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header    Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_redirect      off;
        proxy_pass          http://daphne;
    }
```

Без этого блока все прекрасно работает (кроме самого чата на сайте). Предполагаю что напортачил именно в `docker-compose` но не понимаю где.